# App Crashes sometimes with error in Fabrics java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to Resume Activity

Tags: android

The onResume function that being called

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    refreshTourData();
    if (isNFCReady) { // boolean value checking nfc is ready or npt
        if (pendingIntent != null) // =null when first open the Activity
            mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, techListsArray);
        mNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, null);
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

`refreshTourData();` - Getting List from Sqlite Db and updating

`if (isNFCReady)` - boolean value checking nfc is ready or not Default is false

Error not occuring on regular basic but mostly happen in samsung mobile

Exception :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3842(ActivityThread.java:3842)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3874(ActivityThread.java:3874)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute + 51(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState + 145(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 70(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1830(ActivityThread.java:1830)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6831(ActivityThread.java:6831)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   at android.os.Parcel.createException + 1954(Parcel.java:1954)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1918(Parcel.java:1918)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1868(Parcel.java:1868)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.isTopOfTask + 7920(IActivityManager.java:7920)
   at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask + 6411(Activity.java:6411)
   at android.app.Activity.onResume + 1344(Activity.java:1344)
   at activity.SelectTourActivity.onResume + 799(SelectTourActivity.java:799)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume + 1413(Instrumentation.java:1413)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume + 7292(Activity.java:7292)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 3834(ActivityThread.java:3834)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 3874(ActivityThread.java:3874)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute + 51(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState + 145(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 70(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1830(ActivityThread.java:1830)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6831(ActivityThread.java:6831)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Can anybody suggest me What i am doing wrong in my code

Comment: What is in this line? activity.SelectTourActivity.onResume + 799(SelectTourActivity.java:799)

Comment: super.onResume();

Comment: What is your SelectTourActivity parent? custom class or what?

Comment: It is simple class Activity which is called to select the item then provide the description of item on next page on selection of that particular item

Comment: Try to call super.onResume() before refresh tour data. Maybe you got exception because activity is not resumed and you try to change some UI or other staff which need live activity

Comment: i tried the same solution in previous version of my app but cannot able to solve this exception that time